# Error while loading css while passing parameter

Tags: laravel

When I return view using route without passing parameter it works fine but if I return to same view using parameter to route the css and js does not load. Why is it so?

```
Route::get('inq', function () {
    return view('inquiry/profile');
});

Route::get('inq/2', function () {
    return view('inquiry/profile');
});
```

Comment: Can you show how you are including the css and js on the page?

Comment: Because your CSS is relative and not absolute, make sure you use a leading `/` before the path to the CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
{{asset('path/to/css')}}
```

when loading assets